# pyparsing partial match or recursion limit hit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

Using pyparsing, I seem to be having trouble understanding why my grammar either matches partially or hits a recursion limit.

```
lparens = Suppress("(")
rparens = Suppress(")")
name = Word(alphanums, exact=1)
expression = Forward()
function = Group(Literal("λ") + OneOrMore(name) + Literal(".").suppress() + expression)
application = Group(expression + expression) #<-- the problem *I think*
exp1 = ( name | function | application )
exp2 = (lparens + exp1 + rparens) | exp1
expression << exp2
```

So the following will parse but only picks up the "a" and does not apply the application step:

```
expression.parseString("ab") #result is: (['a'], {})
expression.parseString("(ab)") #result is: exception - recursion limit reached.
```

In the first example why did it stop at 'a' and not apply the application step and run into the same infinite look it does in the second example?

In the second example it matches '(' and so it needs the ')' to finish the exp1. So it should parse the name 'a' and since there is no following ')' it should abandon that and try function (which fails) and then move on to application. Then it parses name 'a' (first match) and should move on to name 'b' completing the name, the application, and then match ')' to complete the exp1 and the expression.

Obviously this is not what happens.

edit: forgot to add the following works:

```
expression.parseString("((λa.a)(λa.a))")
```

` #result: ([([(['λ', 'a', 'a'], {}), (['λ', 'a', 'a'], {})], {})], {})

adding `setDebug()` and `setName()` to the various elements and parsing '(ab)' yields:

```
Match expression at loc 0(1,1)
Match exp2 at loc 0(1,1)
Match lparens at loc 0(1,1)
Matched lparens -> []
Match exp1 at loc 1(1,2)
Match name at loc 1(1,2)
Matched name -> ['a']
Matched exp1 -> ['a']
Match rparens at loc 2(1,3)
Exception raised:Expected ")" (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
Match name at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match function at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected "λ" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match application at loc 0(1,1)
Match expression at loc 0(1,1)
Match exp2 at loc 0(1,1)
Match lparens at loc 0(1,1)
Matched lparens -> []
Match exp1 at loc 1(1,2)
Match name at loc 1(1,2)
Matched name -> ['a']
Matched exp1 -> ['a']
Match rparens at loc 2(1,3)
Exception raised:Expected ")" (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
Match name at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match function at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected "λ" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match application at loc 0(1,1)
Match expression at loc 0(1,1)
Match exp2 at loc 0(1,1)
Match lparens at loc 0(1,1)
Matched lparens -> []
Match exp1 at loc 1(1,2)
Match name at loc 1(1,2)
... etc etc etc...
```

Comment: If I force the use of parentheses by changing `exp2 = (lparens + exp1 + rparens)` then things work better but '(a)(b)' still only parses the 'a'.

Comment: likewise if I just use parentheses like '((a)(b))' it will parse... thus the more complicated example worked because it followed that example. '(a)b' also works -- so I am pretty sure it is never making it past the first name in 'ab'

Comment: Try adding [`setDebug`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setDebug) to your ParserElements to trace what is going on.

Comment: I added that -- and setName so that it was a little more readable. Still trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: As far as I can tell the problem seems to be that as soon as it can say it has a match it does so when it matches 'a' that satisfies exp1 but then exp2 fails with the rparens and so it backs all the way out and tries exp1 so name, function, and then application -- here it all starts over.

Comment: Well I made the following modifications:
`exp1 = ( name | function ) + Optional(expression)` 
`exp2 = (lparens + exp1 + rparens) + Optional(expression) | exp1`
`expression << exp2`
This seems to have helped the parsing but does not really result in the best AST... perhaps all will become clear after a good night's sleep.

Comment: Yes, this term `application = Group(expression + expression)` was causing your infinite recursion problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with your question, as I did not really have a good grasp of just what you were trying to parse. Fortunately, the lambda character in your function definition was enough of a tip-off that I searched for some background on lambda calculus notation, and found a decent description here: http://palmstroem.blogspot.com/2012/05/lambda-calculus-for-absolute-dummies.html

From this I came up with a simple BNF:

```
expr ::= (name | function | '(' expr ')')+
function ::= 'λ' name+ '.' expr
name ::= a single character 'a'..'z' or 'A'..'Z'
```

Translating to pyparsing from here looks like:

```
lparens = Suppress("(")
rparens = Suppress(")")
dot = Suppress('.')
# work around output encoding issues by displaying as '^'
λ = Literal('λ').setParseAction(replaceWith('^'))

# Forward() placeholder for recursive expression
expression = Forward()

# implement BNF bottom-up
name = oneOf(list(alphas))
function = Group(λ + Group(OneOrMore(name))("head") + dot + expression("body"))
lambda_term = name | function | lparens + expression + rparens
expression <<= Group(OneOrMore(lambda_term))
```

This parses your sample expression as:

```
((λa.a)(λa.a))
[[[[['^', ['a'], ['a']]], [['^', ['a'], ['a']]]]]]
```

This seems like a lot of extra nesting to wade through. We can reduce some of it by tweaking `expression` slightly, to Group only if there are 2 or more expressions, otherwise parse a single ungrouped expression. The tuple multiplication feature lets us define this as:

```
expression <<= Group(lambda_term*(2,)) | lambda_term
```

Giving:

```
[[['^', ['a'], 'a'], ['^', ['a'], 'a']]]
```

Or more clearly:

```
[
    [
        ['^', ['a'], 'a'], 
        ['^', ['a'], 'a']
    ]
]
```

In your posted parser, you also had a concept of "application". I speculate that what you call an application is what the cited article-for-dummies refers to as "resolving". To resolve a function, you take subsequent expressions one-for-one with each name in the function head, and replace the name in the body with its respective expression. I tried to comprehend this at parse time, but struggled with expressions where the function was nested within other functions, or the head and body were defined in nested parentheses, with the replacement expressions separated from the function by several nesting levels. I came to the conclusion that resolution has to be done after parsing of names and functions is complete. The structure that pyparsing imparts to the results should make it straightforward to walk the results and successively resolve names with expressions.

Here is the complete parser code:

```
"""
(from http://palmstroem.blogspot.com/2012/05/lambda-calculus-for-absolute-dummies.html)

BNF:
  expr ::= (name | function | '(' expr ')')+
  name ::= ['a'..'z' 'A'..'Z']+
  function ::= lambda name+ '.' expr
"""

lparens = Suppress("(")
rparens = Suppress(")")
dot = Suppress('.')
# work around output encoding issues by displaying as '^'
λ = Literal('λ').setParseAction(replaceWith('^'))

# Forward() placeholder for recursive expression
expression = Forward()

# implement BNF bottom-up
name = oneOf(list(alphas))
function = Group(λ + Group(OneOrMore(name))("head") + dot + expression("body"))
lambda_term = name | function | lparens + expression + rparens
#~ expression <<= Group(OneOrMore(lambda_term))
expression <<= Group(lambda_term*(2,)) | lambda_term


tests = """\
    ((λa.a)(λa.a))
    (λy.xy) ab
    λx.λy.xzy
""".splitlines()
for t in tests:
    t = t.strip()
    print(t.replace('λ','^'))
    expression.parseString(t, parseAll=True).pprint()
    print()
```

Comment: You know I found a few other BNF's but didn't find this one. The others I found either suffered from the same problem - or resulted in ambiguous AST's. BTW extra thanks for the "The Lambda Calculus for Absolute Dummies" like because honestly that is exactly what is going on here -- I was having trouble with hand substitutions in working out Church arithmetic and so I was going to write a little step-by-step substitution interpreter. I was focused on my task at hand the tripped over the first step. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand why your grammar doesn't get the job done, you first have to understand how pyparsing works. You seem to believe that pyparsing explores all possible paths until it finds one that correctly represents the **entire** input string. This is incorrect. See the following example:

```
exp1 = ( name | function | application )
exp1.parseString("ab") # outputs ['a']
```

Here, "a" is a valid `name` and therefore a valid `exp1`. And that's the result you get. Pyparsing doesn't care about the extra "b". It found a match for `exp1`, so that's where it stops.

---

As for the infinite recursion, the problem is this:

```
application = Group(expression + expression)
exp1 = ( name | function | application )
exp2 = (lparens + exp1 + rparens) | exp1
expression << exp2
```

This means that `application` is a valid `exp1`, which in turn is a valid `exp2`, which is a valid `expression`. This is a problem because `application` is made of `expression`s. So when pyparsing tries to parse an `expression` that's an `application`, it then has to parse *another* `expression` within the first one. This then continues infinitely.

Step by step, here's what happens when we call `expression.parseString("(ab)")` :

1. apply rule `expression`:

   1. apply left side of rule `exp2` (`lparens + exp1 + rparens`):

      1. `(` matches `lparens`
      2. `a` matches `name`
      3. `b` doesn't match `rparens` -> abort
   2. apply right side of rule `exp2` (`exp1`):

      1. apply first option in `( name | function | application )` (`name`):

         1. `(` doesn't match `name` -> abort
      2. apply 2nd option (`function`):

         1. `(` doesn't match `λ` -> abort
      3. apply 3rd option (`application`):

         1. apply rule `application` (`expression + expression`):

            1. apply rule `expression`:

               1. go to start

---

See [Paul McG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44944643/1222951) for a working implementation.